# Как оставить номер предыдущего значения в цикле если имена пользователей одинаковые?

Tags: php

```
<?php foreach ($comments as $commentNum => $comment) { ?>

<div class="username-<?php echo ($commentNum%2); ?>">
<?php echo $comment['user'] .  $comment['message'] ; ?>
</div>

<?php } ?>
```

Собеседников может быть 6 человек.

Комментарии в чате получаются всегда с разных сторон. Если написал один пользователь, как сделать чтоб были эти сообщения с одной стороны?

Answer (score 1):

Решение оказалось проще, достаточно было указать текущего пользователя и отображать ему его собщения слева, а всех остальных справа.

Answer (score -1):

```
<?php

$comments = [
  ['user' => 'User 1', 'message' => 'message 1'],
  ['user' => 'User 2', 'message' => 'message 2'],
  ['user' => 'User 2', 'message' => 'message 3'],
];

// пользователь, оставивший последний коммент в цикле
$lastUser = null;
foreach ($comments as $commentNum => $comment) {

  // если очередное сообщение из цепочки принадлежит "прошлому пользователю", не пишем его имя
  if($comment['user'] === $lastUser) {
    echo $comment['message'] . PHP_EOL;
  // сообщение от "нового пользователя", запоминаем пользователя и пишем его имя
  } else {
    $lastUser = $comment['user'];
    echo $comment['user'] . ': ' .  $comment['message'] . PHP_EOL;
  }
}
```

Выводит

```
User 1: message 1
User 2: message 2
message 3
```

PS. Если пишите чат, то чтобы не обновлять страницу по F5, используйте веб-сокеты или long polling